# After upgrate to Laravel 5.6 i have error 'PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?''

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, php-7.2

After upgrate from Laravel 5.5 to Laravel 5.6 i have error.

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in .../vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php on line 499
```

i'm checking php vershion on server:

> # php -v
>   PHP 7.2.4-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Apr  5 2018 08:53:57) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.2.4-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

Reinstall php and restart apache already did.

I'm have the same project local with same vershion of php and its work!

Answer (score 8):

Remove PHP 7.0.

```
sudo apt-get purge php7.0 php7.0-common
```

It worked for me.